# construct_runtime macro panics in a mock environment while it builds in normal runtime

Tags: frame, testing, substrateinterface

Trying to create a mock environment for testing a pallet, but getting an error msg failed `to resolve: could not find` tt_error_token `in the crate root` whenever trying to add my pallet in the mock environment.

Comment: are you importing the pallet and implementing its `Configs` before adding it to `construct_runtime`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to take this [pallet as a template for yours](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/pallets/template). Is a pallet template from the Substrate Developer Hub repo.

In this you can see how to [mock](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/pallets/template/src/mock.rs) the environment:

```
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
 pub enum Test where
    Block = Block,
    NodeBlock = Block,
    UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
 {
    System: frame_system,
    TemplateModule: pallet_template,
 }
);
```

Adding the pallet_template:

```
impl pallet_template::Config for Test {
  type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
}
```

And how to create the [unit tests](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/pallets/template/src/tests.rs).